# How to display Unit as Second Display Item for same display Order?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I work on SQL server 2012 I face Issue : I can't arrange  Features contain  Unit as second Item display for same Display Order .

for feature family as example

```
'Family' as [Family], 'FamilyMaxValue' as [FamilyMaxValue], 'FamilyUnit' as [FamilyUnit]
```

I need it to be as below

```
'Family' as [Family], 'FamilyUnit' as [FamilyUnit],'FamilyMaxValue' as [FamilyMaxValue]
```

Feature and Unit and max value get same DisplayOrder for every Feature but my issue

How to get Unit as Second Display for same Display Order .

Meaning change will be Order of items separated by comma to display feature Unit as second display  for same Display Order.

```
 create table #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal
(
DKFeatureName  nvarchar(100),
DisplayOrder  int
)
insert into #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal (DKFeatureName,DisplayOrder)
values
('package',1),
('packageUnit',1),
('Family',2),
('FamilyMaxValue',2),
('FamilyUnit',2),
('parts',3),
('partsMaxValue',3),
('partsUnit',3)
DECLARE @Header nvarchar(max)=( select
substring(
    (
        Select  ', '''+ DKFeatureName +''' as ['+ DKFeatureName +']' AS [text()]
        From #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal 
        GROUP BY DKFeatureName
        ORDER BY MIN(DisplayOrder)
        --order by DisplayOrder
       
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 10000) [Columns])
    print @Header
```

Expected Result arrange feature Unit as second display to be as:

```
Feature,FeatureUnit,FeatureMaxValue according to same display Order



'package' as [package], 'packageUnit' as [packageUnit],
'Family' as [Family], 'FamilyUnit' as [FamilyUnit],'FamilyMaxValue' as [FamilyMaxValue],
'parts' as [parts], 'partsUnit' as [partsUnit],'partsMaxValue' as [partsMaxValue]
```

AND I don't Need to Display it  as below :

```
Feature,FeatureMaxValue,FeatureUnit for same Display Order

'package' as [package], 'packageUnit' as [packageUnit],
 'Family' as [Family], 'FamilyMaxValue' as [FamilyMaxValue], 'FamilyUnit' as [FamilyUnit],
 'parts' as [parts], 'partsMaxValue' as [partsMaxValue], 'partsUnit' as [partsUnit]
```

Comment: and after add new column SecondaryDisplayOrder what I do

Comment: can you show me how to do that please

Comment: can i do that within select @header  statement  without change main temp table

Comment: There must be some column in the source data to provide the required order or clear rules to determine the order.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. `QuoteName` does more than add square brackets around a string, it also handles square brackets that occur within the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional column to control the display order if `DisplayOrder` alone is not unique. That will allow you to specify both columns in the `ORDER BY` clause for the desired order:

```
CREATE TABLE #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal
(
    DKFeatureName  nvarchar(100),
    DisplayOrder  int,
    SecondaryDisplayOrder  int
);
INSERT INTO #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal (DKFeatureName,DisplayOrder,SecondaryDisplayOrder)
VALUES
    ('package',1,1),
    ('packageUnit',1,2),
    ('Family',2,1),
    ('FamilyMaxValue',2,3),
    ('FamilyUnit',2,2),
    ('parts',3,1),
    ('partsMaxValue',3,2),
    ('partsUnit',3,3)
DECLARE @Header nvarchar(MAX)=( select
SUBSTRING(
    (
        SELECT  ', '''+ DKFeatureName +''' as ['+ DKFeatureName +']' AS [text()]
        FROM #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal 
        ORDER BY DisplayOrder,SecondaryDisplayOrder
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 10000) [Columns]);
PRINT @Header;
```